# Angular expression rendered in raw format sometimes

Tags: angularjs, rendering

I am building a simple web page using Angular.js. On opening the web page in the browser (Chrome) the page is rendered in raw angular expressions like below
[image: Page rendered with raw Angular Expressions]

On Reloading the page (sometimes 2 - 3 times) the Angular expression is evaluated and rendered properly like below

[image: Page rendered properly]

There is no specific pattern when either of the two scenarios occur. What could the possible reason be ?

**Controller File**

```
(function(){
    var userRole = angular.module('userRoleController', []);

    userRole.controller('userRoleDisplayController', function(){
        this.userRoles = userRolesList;
        this.selectedRole = 0;
        this.selectRole = function(roleID){
            this.selectedRole = roleID;
        };
        this.isSelectedRole = function(roleID){
            console.log(roleID);
            console.log(this.selectedRole === 0 ? true : this.selectedRole === roleID);
            return this.selectedRole === 0 ? true : this.selectedRole === roleID;
        };
        this.showRoleExpander = function(){
            return this.selectedRole
        };
        this.expandAllRoles = function(){
            this.selectedRole = 0;
        };
    });

    userRole.directive('userLogin', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '../../views/template/login.html'

        };
    });

    var userRolesList = [
    {
        role_id: 1,
        role_type: 'Student'
    },
    {
        role_id: 2,
        role_type: 'Admin'
    }];
})();
```

**index.js file**

```
(function(){
    var home = angular.module('home', ['userRoleController']);
})();
```

html file

```
<body ng-app='home'>
    <header>
    </header>
    <aside class='users' ng-controller='userRoleDisplayController as roleDispCtrl'>
        <ul>
            <li class='roles' ng-repeat='userRole in roleDispCtrl.userRoles' ng-show='roleDispCtrl.isSelectedRole(userRole.role_id)'
             ng-click='roleDispCtrl.selectRole(userRole.role_id)'>
                {{userRole.role_type}}              
            </li>
            <li ng-show="roleDispCtrl.showRoleExpander()">
                <user-login>
                </user-login>
            </li>
            <li class="roleExpander" ng-show="roleDispCtrl.showRoleExpander()" ng-click="roleDispCtrl.expandAllRoles()">
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </aside>
    <main>          
    </main> 
    <script charset="utf-8" async defer src="../scripts/JS Frameworks/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" async defer src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" async defer src="../scripts/controllers/userRoleController.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check if there is any error in console when its showing expression in raw format

Comment: thanks manoj. Got this error in console -> Failed to instantiate module home due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=home
    at Error (native)

Comment: I am new to working with Angular. Can you explain what could have caused it ?

Comment: when you are trying to access module "home" before declaring it. Please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod for this error details. 

if you are still facing the same issue, please post the code where you have declared your module.

Comment: from what i read, looks like i am doing it the way its told. Am i doing something wrong that i have overlooked in the docs ?

Comment: Not sure, but i think its async keyword which might cause this error. Scripts start execution as soon as its ready, so before loading controller module, its trying to use it as dependency. refer http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/ for more details.

Could you please try loading scripts without "async" keyword and let me know if it solves your issue?

Comment: Thanks Manoj. It works without using async property !

Answer (score 0):

Often times this happens as a result of some error which causes angular not to load properly. Because the page occasionally loads correctly I would assume the your business logic is probably correct in terms of how you wired things up.  You might try checking some of your dependencies to make sure they are loading correctly.  If you are loading a resource from another domain and it fails to load for whatever reason, it could cause problems which lead to angular failing to load.

Comment: I am not loading anything from other sources. I have this html + a css file and the Angular files separated into index.js and controller.js. The data that is displayed is an array of JS objects that is hard coded in the controller file

Comment: it would be easier to determine the problem if you could post that code.